# bonfire / codeigniter - Assets::add_js - can't add passing arguments

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I need to be able to create a  line that looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/myapp/themes/testtheme/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.2"></script>
```

I've tried the following:

```
Assets::add_js('fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.2');
```

but that fails - it doesn't add anything at all to my header. 
Using:

```
Assets::add_js('fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js');
```

adds a script tag, but without the version number.  It just looks like this:

```
<script src="http://localhost/myapp/bonfire/themes/testtheme/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Can you tell me how to add the ?v=2.1.2 to my script tag?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with Bonfire, but I took a quick look at the source code.

I'm pretty sure the reason it's not displaying the script tag is because it's looking for a file with the literal name `fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.2`, which doesn't exist.

I think you can trick it by using a full url, so it thinks it's an external script and won't check if the file exists. Something like:

```
Assets::add_js(base_url().'fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.2');
```

It's never pleasant to have to use workarounds like this and can sometimes cause side effects, so I would suggest you [point this out to the developer(s) of Bonfire](https://github.com/ci-bonfire/Bonfire/issues/new).

Another thing to note, `?v=2.1.2` is nothing more than a cache-busting trick for when you update the file (it makes users re-download the file when the query string is changed), so consider whether or not you actually need it.

Comment: Wesley, gave that a try and the tag it creates looks like this: <script src="http://localhost/myapp/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack?v=2.1.2.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

Comment: I'm going to look into whether or not I really need the version number specified. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I assume the comment parser ate your `http://` right? So it stripped the query string? Where did that semicolon come from before `type`? That's a little annoying. Did you try with another actual external script and query string?

Comment: You only need the query string version number if the site has been in production (users have the file in their cache), you changed the file content, *and* the file name is the same. Another way to do it is just change the file name (if you really need to). The actual value of the version number is totally meaningless, it's just making the browser think it's a different file.

Comment: There's no need to accept the answer if it doesn't solve the question asked. Your call, but just saying - you don't need to. There are definitely valid reasons to need a query string in the `src` and this post doesn't quite solve that problem. I would leave it open.